# realloc function doesn't preserve existing memory for me

Tags: c++

I created a memory block  with 4 units using calloc function where each unit is 1 byte.

Then I assigned it to a char pointer and filled the units with char values.

Then using realloc function I enlarged each unit to 4 bytes (size of an integer)
Then I assigned it to a int pointer and filled integers in 3 of the units.

Theoretically I expected that the for the 4th unit of the memory block, value I gave before realloc will be preserved. But it is not. When I compile, each time I get a random value for that.

```
 int main() {


    //create a memory block of 4 units (each 1 bytes : char size)
    char *p = (char*)calloc(4,sizeof(char));

    //fill the memory units with chars
    p[0] = 'A';
    p[1] = 'B';
    p[2] = 'C';
    p[3] = 'D';

    //print 
    for(int i = 0; i< 4 ; i++){
        printf("%c \n",p[i]);
    }

    //print integer value of third index
    printf("Third index integer value : %d\n",p[3]);

    printf("\n"); //space



    //change the memory block so that each unit = 4 byte (size of integers)
    int  *B = (int*)realloc(p, sizeof(int));
    p = NULL;


    //fill 3 of the 4 memory units with integers
    B[0] = 20;
    B[1] = 25;
    B[2] = 30;


    //print integers
    printf("%d \n", B[0]);
    printf("%d \n", B[1]);
    printf("%d \n", B[2]);
    printf("Third index integer value : %d \n", B[3]);

    printf("Third index char value : %c \n", B[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Outcome

**attempt 1**

```
B 
C 
D 
Third index integer value : 68

20 
25 
30 
Third index integer value : 53491 
Third index char value : ó
```

**attempt 2**

```
A 
B 
C 
D 
Third index integer value : 68

20 
25 
30 
Third index integer value : 42319 
Third index char value : O
```

Comment: `B[anything_but_zero]` is out-of-range access. *"Then using realloc function I enlarged each unit to 4 bytes (size of an integer) "* is not true.

Comment: Side note: `size(char)` is a pointless expression, its value is `1` by definition (`sizeof` returns the size in number of `char` objects).

Comment: Please, remember that in C you always have to free the allocated memory, while in C++ it's way better to use containers like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Read suitable [documentation of `realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc): its size parameter is the new size of memory to allocate. You're asking it to allocate `sizeof(int)` bytes, which is likely `4` (the same as the size of your previous allocation).

From the C-style allocation functions, `calloc` is the only one which works in terms of cells & cell size. Everything else (`malloc`, `realloc`, even the C++ allocation functions `::operator new` and `::operator new[]`) works in raw memory size only. So change you call to:

```
int  *B = (int*)realloc(p, 4 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: also FYI: The reason you're seeing garbage on your last 2 printfs is that when you're allocating heap (malloc/realloc/calloc), the OS typically gives you memory in page sizes (4k).  And those pages are dirty.  Only calloc guarantees to zero out the data.